# method doClick() doesn't work

Tags: java, junit

Hy everyone! I'm trying to do a test in junit on my application but I have a problem: I have some buttons with random letters everytime and I'm trying to build a certain word by clicking certain letters, for example "are" but when I use the method doClick it doesn't work. Can anyone tell me why? My code looks like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
    if (ClassicGame.lit[i].getText() == "A" && litGasitaA == false) {
        ClassicGame.lit[i].doClick();
        litGasitaA = true;
        System.out.println("S-a apasat litera A" + ClassicGame.lit[i].getText());
    }
    if (ClassicGame.lit[i].getText() == "R" && litGasitaR == false) {
        ClassicGame.lit[i].doClick();
        litGasitaR = true;
    }
    if (ClassicGame.lit[i].getText() == "E" && litGasitaE == false) {
        ClassicGame.lit[i].doClick();
        litGasitaR = true;
    }
    System.out.println("Literele:" + ClassicGame.lit[i].getText());
}
```

Comment: `ClassicGame.lit[i].getText()=="A"`. No don't use `==`, use `equals()` instead.

Comment: Did you know that each time a programmer use `==` instead of `equals` god kills a dinosaur?

Comment: @ZouZou likely has the answer to your problem. On a side note, your code appears as if you're using static variables where you shouldn't. If the above variables are in fact static, you should strongly consider re-structuring your program so that these are instance variables. You might not see it now, but doing so will make it much easier to extend, enhance, debug and test.